# "Link" is not navigating to the specified routes - React JS (react-route-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working with React JS routes and installed `react-route-dom`. I have two main components, `side-bar.js` and `nav.js`. `side-bar.js` has some components like `discussion.js`, `friends.js` etc that should be loaded according to the provided URL/specified path.

I have specified the routes in the `side-bar.js` and `<Links to="/path" />` in the `nav.js`. When I click the link on `nav.js` it changes the specified path (the URL is changed) but the route is still the same (the same component is shown), as it should switch between the `discussion.js`, `friends.js` etc. But on the other hand, when I refresh the page with the specified paths in the `<Link to="/discussion"/>`, the required component is loaded accordingly. I don't know what the problem is that it only works on page refresh and not with link.

**`side-bar.js` code**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Discussion from './side-bar-components/discussion'
import Friends from './side-bar-components/friends'
import Notifications from './side-bar-components/notifications'
import Settings from './side-bar-components/settings'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


export class sidebar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="tab-content">
                        <Router>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path={'/'} exact component={Discussion}/>
                                <Route path={'/discussion'} component={Discussion}/>
                                <Route path={'/friends'}  component={Friends}/>
                                <Route path={'/notifications'}  component={Notifications}/>
                                <Route path={'/settings'}  component={Settings}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </Router>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default sidebar
```

**`nav.js` code**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

export class nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <nav className="navigation">
                    <div className="container">
                        <a href="#nav" className="logo" rel="home"> <img src="dist/img/logo.png" alt="logo" /> </a>
                        <ul className="nav" role="tablist">
                            <BrowserRouter>
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/discussion">
                                        <i data-eva="message-square" data-eva-animation="pulse"></i>
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/friends">
                                        <i data-eva="people" data-eva-animation="pulse"></i>
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/notifications">
                                        <i data-eva="bell" data-eva-animation="pulse"></i>
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/settings">
                                        <i data-eva="settings" data-eva-animation="pulse"></i>
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                                <li><button type="button" className="btn mode"><i data-eva="bulb" data-eva-animation="pulse"></i></button></li>
                                <li><button type="button" className="btn"><img src="dist/img/avatars/avatar-male-1.jpg" alt="avatar" /><i data-eva="radio-button-on"></i></button></li>
                            </BrowserRouter>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default nav
```

**`home.js` code (Parent Component)**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Nav from './app-components/nav'
import Sidebar from './app-components/sidebar'
import Compose from './app-components/compose'
import Chat from './app-components/chat'


export class home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             
        }
    }


    

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="layout">

                <Nav />
                <Sidebar />
                <Chat />
                <Compose />
            
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default home
```

Comment: Can you include the parent of both components please

Comment: You should not wrap your nav.js with another BrowserRouter, this component should be unique in our structure. Probably you're messing up with this structure somewhere, you need to have everything wrapped inside (the same) BrowserRouter, both your Routes and your Links.

Comment: @AsafAviv updated

Comment: @RenanSouza, when I don't wrap the `<Link />` with `<Router />` it through an error.

Comment: Then you need to work out why this is happening and understand the routing structure. Check on the docs and follow them, its pretty easy and way better, also, you will really understand what you're doing. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove `BrowserRouter` from `nav` and handle the routes from the parent component.

Include the components you want to always show inside `Router` but outside of `Switch` and the components you want to act as pages inside `Route`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Link,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const renderLink = path => <Link to={`/${path}`}>{path}</Link>;

const NestedDiscussion = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>nested route for discussion {match.params.id}</h1>
  </div>
);

const Discussion = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>discussion</h1>
    <Link to={`${match.url}/1`}>Discussion 1</Link>
    <Link to={`${match.url}/2`}>Discussion 2</Link>
    <Link to={`${match.url}/3`}>Discussion 3</Link>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/:id`} component={NestedDiscussion} />
  </div>
);

const Friends = () => <h3>Friends</h3>;
const Notifications = () => <h3>Notifications</h3>;
const Settings = () => <h3>Settings</h3>;

class SideBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="tab-content">SideBar</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navigation">
        <div className="container">
          <ul className="nav" role="tablist">
            {renderLink("discussion")}
            {renderLink("friends")}
            {renderLink("notifications")}
            {renderLink("settings")}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <SideBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path={"/"}
            exact
            render={() => <Redirect to="/discussion" />}
          />
          <Route path={"/discussion"} component={Discussion} />
          <Route path={"/discussion/:id"} component={Discussion} />
          <Route path={"/friends"} component={Friends} />
          <Route path={"/notifications"} component={Notifications} />
          <Route path={"/settings"} component={Settings} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4htf3)

Comment: @NadeemAhmad What do you mean by dynamic ? Do you mean nested routes ? like `<Route path="/discussion/:id" />`  ?

Comment: Yes, I meant nested routes.

Comment: @NadeemAhmad I've updated the answer and sandbox to show to you can create nested routes

Comment: As you can see from my codes, the `home.js` has four children and then `side-bar.js` has four more children. The components that should be loaded according to the `route`, they should load inside the `side-bar.js` not home.

Comment: @NadeemAhmad Take my answer as an example and implement the structure you need yourself. I don't know how your app structure should look like

Comment: I had to specify the `<BrowserRouter>` in the parent, your example worked perfect thank you.